# How can I include inviter's name in devise_invitable invitation view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

I have tried adding %{first_name} or %{current_user.first_name} to yml file and to the view. I get error,

`ActionView::Template::Error (missing interpolation argument :first_name`

How can I add "name" has invited you! instead of "Someone has invited you" which is the default and is likely to be seen as a spam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find the user by the `invited_by_id`

```
@user = User.find(resource.invited_by_id)
```

Here is a link, Open the [link](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#label-Sending+an+invitation+after+user+creation) and scroll up above the heading `Sending an invitation after user creation`